# Load image async as Bitmap and get exception

Tags: android, android-glide

I need to load **asynchronically** image to bitmap. And if not success load then **get exception**. Here snippet:

```
 private Bitmap bannerImageBitmap;

        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imageURL)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .skipMemoryCache(false)
                .addListener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        // do some with exception
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        bannerImageBitmap = resource;
                        onLoadSuccess();
                        return false;
                    }
                }).submit();
    }
```

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: please post the exception

Comment: Why? I need only to understand is I'm use async approach.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is asynchronous. If you use sophisticated library like Glide, it would automatically load images managing thread creation and removal leaving you nothing to worry for.